# Spark Read CSV doesn't preserve the double quotes while reading

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read a csv file with one column has double quotes like below.

```
James,Butt,"Benton, John B Jr",6649 N Blue Gum St
Josephine,Darakjy,"Chanay, Jeffrey A Esq",4 B Blue Ridge Blvd
Art,Venere,"Chemel, James L Cpa",8 W Cerritos Ave #54
Lenna,Paprocki,Feltz Printing Service,639 Main St,Anchorage
Donette,Foller,Printing Dimensions,34 Center St,Hamilton
Simona,Morasca,"Chapman, Ross E Esq",3 Mcauley Dr
```

I am using the below code to keep the double quotes as its from the csv file.(few rows having double quotes and few dont)

```
 val df_usdata    = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")//
.option("header","true")//
.option("quote","\"")//
.load("file:///E://data//csvdata.csv")
df_usdata.show(false)
```

But it didn't preserve the double quotes inside the dataframe but it should be.
The .option("quote",""") is not working. Am using Spark 2.3.1 version.

The output should be like below.

```
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|first_name|last_name|company_name             |address              |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
|James     |Butt     |"Benton, John B Jr"      |6649 N Blue Gum St   |
|Josephine |Darakjy  |"Chanay, Jeffrey A Esq"  |4 B Blue Ridge Blvd  |
|Art       |Venere   |"Chemel, James L Cpa"    |8 W Cerritos Ave #54 |
|Lenna     |Paprocki |Feltz Printing Service   |639 Main St          |
|Donette   |Foller   |Printing Dimensions      |34 Center St         |
|Simona    |Morasca  |"Chapman, Ross E Esq"    |3 Mcauley Dr         |
+----------+---------+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: if you set `.option("quote","\"")` then spark will not preserve `"`.

Comment: So, what could be the solution to preserve the " (doble quotes). I tried both .option("quote","") and .option("quote","\u0000"). They did preserve the quotes but column values has been splitted into next column due to  comma delimiter. You can see the below result.

Answer (score 0):

Try empty quotes `.option("quote","")` instead.

```
val df_usdata = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")//
.option("header","true")//
.option("quote","")//
.load("file:///E://data//csvdata.csv")
df_usdata.show(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay! It tried with the .option("quote","")//. But the column value splitted into next column like below.                                                                                                    

|James     |Butt     |"Benton           | John B Jr"          |
|Josephine |Darakjy  |"Chanay     | Jeffrey A Esq"|
|Art       |Venere        |"Chemel     | James L Cpa" |